# O que é redundância de dados em cloud computing?

Tags: terminologia, cloud

O que é redundância de dados, quando se refere à *cloud computing* e qual é sua importância para o serviço?

Comment: Redundância, em geral, é você ter mais de um do mesmo, para aguentar falhas. Se usar um Raid 1 de 5 discos de HD, você terá 5 discos com o mesmo dado, se um falhar (ou se quatro falharem) você ainda tem os dados. É comum servidores utilizarem mais de uma fonte de energia, assim em caso de falha a outra ainda mantêm funcionando.... Isso é aplicado a _tudo_ basicamente. Redundância de dados é ter o mesmo dado em vários discos, maquinas, regiões diferentes. Isto tem o intuito de que os dados sobrevivam e estejam SEMPRE disponíveis, mesmo se passar um furação em um dos data centers.

Comment: @Inkeliz Poste isso como resposta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redundância não é algo exclusivo da computação e muito menos do *cloud computing*, na verdade ela tem exatamente a mesma característica até no português.

Na língua portuguesa, dizer "sair pra fora", "subir pra cima", "metades iguais", "países do mundo" (...) é considerado redundante (e também dão o nome de pleonasmo vicioso), isso ocorre porque existe um repetição, dizendo a mesma coisa duas vezes.

A área da computação, em geral, é cercada por "redundâncias". A diferença que na maioria das vezes isso é considerado benéfico,  *ao contrário da língua portuguesa, que é um erro*.

---

### GERAL

A redundância é utilizada/criada para manter o dispositivo/sistema disponível sempre, sem interrupções ou perdas de dados. A redundância é ter ao menos duas "coisa" que sejam capazes de operar tranquilamente mesmo se uma "coisa" deixar de funcionar.

Você pode criar/utilizar redundâncias em vários lugares, como...

**Fonte/PSU:**

[image: PSU]

Você pode ter duas fontes de energia, isso permitirá que o servidor se manter disponível mesmo se um deles morrer. O servidor ficará indisponível apenas se ambos deixarem de funcionar e a probabilidade disso ocorrer é menor quanto mais fontes houverem. *Para computadores pessoais isso não é utilizado, acredito eu.*

**HDD/SSD:**
[image: Raid]

Este é talvez o mais importante e o mais utilizado. Utilizar mais de um disco permitirá ter melhor performance e/ou maior confiabilidade. Para isso existe o [RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) que nada mais do que a forma que irá utilizar o conjunto de discos, *afinal você pode utilizar eles individualmente*.

Os modos de RAID mais comum, *mas isso é minha opinião*, é o RAID 0, RAID 1 e RAID 5. Irei resumir o funcionamento deles. O RAID 0 melhora a performance, mas reduz a confiabilidade, ele divide os arquivos entre os discos, se um morrer todos os arquivos são perdidos. O RAID 1 tem todos mesmos arquivos para todos os discos, assim você tem o mesmo arquivo em todos os discos, se um morrer nada é afetado, porém a performance não é prioridade, além disso todos os discos possuem o mesmo dado, não havendo "soma" da capacidade de armazenamento. O RAID 5 é mais complexo, ele divide os arquivos porém reserva 1/3 do disco como um "backup", sendo um pouco mais tolerante a falha, porém se dois discos morrerem já era.

*Você também pode "somar" os RAID, como o RAID 10 (que é um RAID 1 + RAID 0) ou pode utilizar múltiplos RAID, por exemplo dois discos com RAID 1 e outros dois com RAID 0, distintos entre si.*

Existe também um BBU que é uma bateria especifica para o cache do disco (na verdade o cache do controlador do disco), assim caso haja uma queda no fornecimento de energia dos discos o cache vai permanecer disponível. Assim, os dados, do cache, serão gravados quando os discos estiverem funcionando novamente.

**CPU:**
[image: CPU]

Você pode ter dois processadores num mesmo servidor, mas isso não indica que será aprova de falhas! Poucos são os processadores que são capazes de suportar que um dos processadores morram, processadores da Intel e AMD, até onde eu saiba, não são tolerantes a falha deste tipo. Se possuir 2x "Processadores Intel", se um deles queimar irá deixar de funcionar, independente se o outro ainda funciona. Apenas processadores da IBM (como o Power8) aparentam ser capazes de suportar essa situação, funcionando sozinho com o outro queimado.

A Intel por sua vez possui "núcleos redundantes", [ao menos tem uma patente para isso, se isto for verdade](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/intel-patent-many-core-processor-multicore,14205.html). Se isto estiver em uso alguns processadores da Intel possuem núcleos extras que podem ser utilizados em caso de falha ou podem ser utilizados justamente para reduzir a falha o "núcleo original", *mas isso já está dentro dele, não é você "quem faz".*

**RAM:**

[image: RAM]

Existem alguns processadores da Intel, que possuem um recurso de "Mirrored Mode RAM", ele é "idêntico" ao RAID 1. Ele duplica os dados da RAM para o correspondente do mesmo channel, *ou seja existe um "RAID 1" por channel*, dessa forma se usar 4x 16GB, ele terá 32GB utilizáveis *e não 64GB*, *supondo que seja duas memorias por canal, obviamente.*

A RAM é conhecida por ser volátil, por não guardar dados por longa duração. Por isso a única vantagem de utilizar esse recurso é que o dispositivo poderá ser utilizado mesmo se uma RAM por channel deixar de funcionar, desde que reste uma RAM por channel está tudo "100%". *Se todas as memorias do mesmo "canal" derem problema, além de muito azar terá muita tela azul.*

A IBM tem um tal de RAIM, que segue a mesma logica acima e a mesma ideia do RAID, só que para RAM. *A diferença é que eu não sei muitas informações, as informações sobre IBM é meio obscuro para mim.*

---

Mas ainda não acabou não, mas se fosse listar tudo nunca iria terminar isso.

Você também pode ter geradores e baterias para sobreviver uma queda de energia, inclusive o StackOverflow teve uns problema enquanto um furação estava por lá, em 2012, salvo engano.

Além disso tem a rede de internet, afinal o que adianta manter tudo ligado se não tem internet? Uma boa redundância é utilizar diferentes provedores e diferentes rotas de conexão justamente para serem capazes de suportar a queda de uma das conexões, assim mesmo se romper uma fibra óptica no caminho a gente tem outra conexão que da conta.

---

### CLOUD

Agora soma tudo que está ali em cima, ou pelo menos os principais, e junte isso com o sistema "cloud" que está disponível no AWS, Rackspace, Azure, Google Cloud e por aí vai.

A ideia é a mesma, só que com mais recursos.

**Múltiplas localizações/"maquinas":**
[image: Vários locais]

Se você em apenas um local e sem qualquer tipo de redundância já é difícil de ocorrer algum problema, imagine utilizando RAID e múltiplos PSU em vários países diferentes? Pode passar vários furações, tsunamis (...) e a chance de que isso destrua todos os dados é difícil.

Ter servidores "clonados" em várias regiões faz com que o website, por exemplo, esteja disponível sempre e com a menor downtime possível. Você pode balancear o trafego utilizando DNS, assim se um servidor estiver indisponível ou estiver instável, ele utilizará outro servidor de outro local, por exemplo.

**"Migração":**
[image: Cloud]

Uma das diferenças do "cloud" é que você não a posse de um servidor em si, ao contrário do dedicado. Isso torna mais fácil migrar entre servidores. Imagine que você tem 5 "maquinas" em 5 locais diferentes, um delas deixa de funcionar, sabe-se lá por qual motivo, você pode simplesmente destruir a instancia problemática e criar uma nova copiando o que tinha nas outras, simples assim.

Enquanto isso, se você tem um servidor dedicado para um website, por exemplo, e a placa-mãe deixa de funcionar, você terá que aguardar até que um humano verifique o problema, remova placa, substitua... Enquanto no Cloud, desde que possua uma outra instancia "como referencia" poderá migrar ela tranquilamente. *Já tive um problema desse no Rackspace, um dos servidores do Rackspace Database morreu, sei lá porque, mas o website continuou funcionando normalmente e em alguns minutos no suporte transferiram para outro servidor, magia negra, dai os dois voltaram a funcionar e não teve nenhum impacto nem antes, durante e nem depois.*

---

### Quando usar redundância?

Sempre que não quiser perder os dados, por exemplo para o banco de dados é ideal que possua redundância de discos, backups espalhados e servidores ao redor do mundo. Isso irá garantir que os dados vão estar disponíveis sempre que precisar e que nenhum dado será perdido, assim atingindo os dois objetivos.

Você deve utilizar todas as redundâncias possíveis, em tudo que é lugar, se realmente deseja que o serviço fique sempre disponível. Imagine que possua um website e deseja que ele fique 100% online, mesmo se um servidor parar de funcionar. Se possuir várias instanciais/maquinas o website ainda funcionará porque o DNS já está apontando para o novo servidor ou o load balance já foi ajustado para a nova instancia. Enquanto isso se possuir replicas do MySQL, se um servidor do MySQL der um tilt você poderá usar o website normalmente todos os dados e tudo operando como se nada tivesse ocorrido, simples assim, graças a todas as redundâncias.

### Qual a desvantagem de usar redundância?

Em geral custo. Você terá que pagar duas vezes, três vezes, quatro vezes para ter exatamente a mesma coisa que já tem. Você não vai ganhar performance, vai apenas torna-lo mais confiável.

Um lugar onde o custo disso fica claro é no RAID 1, imagina ter 4 discos de SSD/HDD em RAID 1, você tem exatamente o mesmo espaço de apenas 1 disco. Se você  tem 4 discos de 1 TB você terá apenas 1 TB livre para ser utilizado, apenas.

Agora estenda isso para ter vários servidores idênticos ao redor do mundo, se considerar que ter uma instancia/servidor já é caro, ter duas, três ou quatro delas iguais será ainda mais custoso.

Existe também o problema de performance. Gravar grande volume de dados em um disco já pode ser lento, imagina gravar em vários discos diferentes? Nem estou contando com o uso de rede para manter todos os dados sincronizados entre os servidores. Existe um impacto negativo na performance, não estou dizendo que isto impede o uso do RAID 1 ou da "RAM espelhada", por exemplo, mas ele existe. Para performance (independente de qualquer coisa) é muito melhor usar um RAID 0 (ou até mesmo "Sem RAID") do que utilizar o RAID 1, na maior parte das situações.

### Quando não usar redundância?

Sempre que os dados não são importantes ou quando ter uma alta disponibilidade não é prioridade.

No exemplo acima do banco de dados, você pode fazer um RAID 1 para evitar perda de dados. Entretanto, se você tem um banco de dados que utiliza muita tabela temporária em disco para que você vai usar um RAID 1 numa pasta temporária? Uma outra opção seria utilizar um RAID 0 somente para a pasta temporária. Assim, a leitura e gravação seria infinitamente mais rápida e você não precisa desses dados temporários.

Entretanto, isso vai fazer com que caso o RAID 0 dê problema o servidor ficará indisponível. Mas os dados do banco de dados, que estão nos discos em RAID 1, ainda vão estar salvos, ou é esperado que estejam.

Acho que deu para entender. Não se usa redundância quando está disposto a sacrificar a disponibilidade do serviço.

É logico, se o servidor do banco de dados, da situação acima, tiver um replica, ou for um slave, isso não é um problema. Se o RAID 0 morrer de um servidor ainda está tudo bem, existem replicas que serão utilizadas em seu lugar.

---

OPINIÃO: Se está usando o "cloud" eu iria sugerir para que tenha pelo menos replicas em outros locais, do mesmo provedor e backups em outro provedor. O ponto mais critico na minha opinião é o banco de dados, lá nada pode ser pedido, invista o quanto puder nele. Na minha opinião se o website/software ficar offline por algumas horas (ou até dias) não é um problema grave se comparado a perder dados do banco.

> Lembre-se de fazer backup, RAID e replicas NÃO SÃO BACKUPS!